# How to add accessibility id to React-Native app?

Tags: react-native, appium, accessibility

I'm trying to automatize an react-native app using Appium, but i need accessibility id to identify elements. I've tried with the following code but still not showing accesibilty id.
`

```
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={opacity}
      onPress={onPress}
      disabled={disabled}
      accessible={true}
      accessibilityLabel="Ingresar a mi cuenta"
      testID="loginAccount"
    >
```

`

I managed to modify the xpath of the Tab screen with attributes:

```
tabBarTestID: 'Inicio', tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'inicioLabel'
```

Also i want to know if it works in custom components.

I've tried adding testId, accesible and testID, but still not showing accesibiltyID

Comment: Hi. I haven’t worked with React native yet, but _accessibilityID_ seems a weird concept to me and I can’t find that keyword on the docs. [I do find _nativeID_](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#nativeid), though. Could that be it?

Comment: Hi @Andy . accessibilityID is how is shown inside the tool Appium Inspector. But it´s not the same label on react-native, for example "tabBarTestID"  in react-native gets "translated" to accessibilityID in appium inspector. I will look the page, thanks!